# Правильная организация наследования

Tags: javascript, наследование

Пытаюсь организовать наследование такого типа (Напиток > Алкогольный/Без алкогольный > Пиво/Вода (к определенным функциям)).

Не могу понять как это все правильно организовать, делаю по примеру на learnjs.

```
function Drink(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.turnovers = 0;
}

Drink.prototype.turn = function(turnovers) {
    this.turnovers += turnovers;
    console.log( this.name + ' оборотов: ' + this.turnovers );
};

function Alcohol(name) {

}

function noAlcohol(name) {

}
```

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее что на что должны ссылаться? Т.е у Alcohol и noAlcohol должны быть свои методы не доступные друг для друга, но в обоих должны быть доступны методы Drink ?

Comment: используй ES7 классы, там всё проще - [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_extends)

Comment: @Lukas об этом в задании ничего не сказано, просто реализовать иерархию классов и тематика

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложно понять что именно вам нужно. Из текущего кода я бы сделал примерно так:

```js
function Drink(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.turnovers = 0;
}

Drink.prototype.turn = function(turnovers) {
    this.turnovers += turnovers;
    console.log( this.name + ' оборотов: ' + this.turnovers );
};

function Alcohol(name) {
Drink.apply(this, arguments);
}

function NoAlcohol(name) {
Drink.apply(this, arguments);
}

Alcohol.prototype.__proto__ = Drink.prototype;
NoAlcohol.prototype.__proto__ = Drink.prototype;

let alcohol = new Alcohol("Rum");
alcohol.turn(40);

let noAlcohol = new NoAlcohol("water")
noAlcohol.turn(0);
```